# Calculating Manhatten distance between all pairs

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, optimization, time-complexity

I have a list(vector in c++) of (x,y) coordinates of some vertices from a matrix e.g `[ (0,2) , (0,3) , (1,2) , (2,2) ]` . I want to calculate Manhattan distance between each pair of vertices in the list.
Currently I am using two loops:

```
for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++)
            {
                dist=abs(v[i][0]-v[j][0])+abs(v[i][1]-v[j][1]);
                //Process dist
            }
        }
```

This approach has a time complexity of O(n^2). Is there a better approach to do this which has less time complexity?

Comment: Maybe not, as the amount of pairs is of this order

Comment: Your "Manhatten distance" algorithm's complexity is `O(1)`. You just invoke it for each two pairs. In other words, the only way to simplify the situation -- change the number of pairs or abuse some kind of similarities between them.

Comment: I want to calculate manhatten distance between all pairs. The complete algorithm has O(n^2) time.

Comment: If you want to calculate distance between all pairs, it will be O(n^2). Why are you surprised? You have to go through each and every pair(visit it) to calculate it. There is no question of efficiency in this. Probably you can remember a point and avoid calculating the distance for the same point, but that won't improve the complexity in any significant way, unless there are a lot of duplicate points.

Answer (score 0):

As the size of your output is `\Theta(n^2)` and complexity of each Manhattan distance for each pair is in `O(1)`, you can't improve the complexity anymore.